# Corda: How to implement hierarchical relationships between state data persisted to H2

Tags: hibernate, jpa, h2, corda

***Summary***

I've adapted the basic Token Issuance Corda Bootcamp application to demonstrate this issue. I want to create a bidirectional mapping between TokenStates and TokenChildren where the relationship is one-to-many.

*What are the best practices for persisting hierarchical data? Is it possible to implement this using JPA annotations in state schemas?*

I have one state - `TokenState`, that contains some arbitrary data as well as a `Collection` of objects with the class `TokenChild`. The purpose of this list is to facilitate a one-to-many relationship between the records in H2. The state's associated schema has corresponding JPA annotations (@OneToMany and @ManyToOne - see code snippet below). The `TokenState` class references the appropriate schema - `TokenSchemaV1` in the `supportedSchemas` and `generateMappedObject` methods.

When I run `TokenIssueFlow` (also included as a snippet) from the console after deploying and running the nodes, the transaction succeeds but no `token_child_states` table is persisted to h2.

***Other Notes***

- I've also tried to implement a different strategy where both Tokens
  and TokenChildren are unique states (rather than one monolithic
  state). See [this Github issue](https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/4193) for more details.
- Another solution might be having Tokens and TokenChildren as
  separate states and manually persisting foreign keys in h2 to
  facilitate this relationship but that seems like a work-around more than 
  a solution.
- What are the ramifications for an even more deeply nested relationship 
  between classes? (e.g. - a contrived example of TokenChildren having 
  TokenGrandChildren and so forth). How do I use `generateMappedObject()` 
  and `supportedSchemas()` to create the data model I need?

***TokenState***

```html
public class TokenState implements LinearState, QueryableState {

    private final Party owner;
    private final Party issuer;
    private final int amount;
    private final UniqueIdentifier linearId;
    private List<TokenSchemaV1.PersistentChildToken> listOfPersistentChildTokens;

    public TokenState (Party issuer, Party owner, int amount, UniqueIdentifier linearId, List<TokenSchemaV1.PersistentChildToken> listOfPersistentChildTokens) {
        this.owner = owner;
        this.issuer = issuer;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.linearId = linearId;
        this.listOfPersistentChildTokens = listOfPersistentChildTokens;
    }

    public Party getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public Party getIssuer() {
        return issuer;
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    @Override
    public UniqueIdentifier getLinearId() {
        return linearId;
    }

    public List<TokenSchemaV1.PersistentChildToken> getListOfPersistentChildTokens() {
        return listOfPersistentChildTokens;
    }

    @Override
    public PersistentState generateMappedObject(MappedSchema schema) {
        if (schema instanceof TokenSchemaV1) {
            return new TokenSchemaV1.PersistentToken(
                    this.getOwner().getName().toString(),
                    this.getIssuer().getName().toString(),
                    this.getAmount(),
                    this.linearId.getId(),
                    this.getListOfPersistentChildTokens()
            );
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unrecognised schema $schema");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<MappedSchema> supportedSchemas() {
        return ImmutableList.of(new TokenSchemaV1());
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public List<AbstractParty> getParticipants() {
        return ImmutableList.of(issuer, owner);
    }

}
```

***TokenSchemaV1***

```html
@CordaSerializable
public class TokenSchemaV1 extends MappedSchema {

    public TokenSchemaV1() {
        super(TokenSchema.class, 1, ImmutableList.of(PersistentToken.class, PersistentChildToken.class));
    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "token_states")
    public static class PersistentToken extends PersistentState {
        @Column(name = "owner") private final String owner;
        @Column(name = "issuer") private final String issuer;
        @Column(name = "amount") private final int amount;
        @Column(name = "linear_id") private final UUID linearId;
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "persistentToken") private final List<PersistentChildToken> listOfPersistentChildTokens;
        //get() = field

        public PersistentToken(String owner, String issuer, int amount, UUID linearId, List<PersistentChildToken> listOfPersistentChildTokens) {
            this.owner = owner;
            this.issuer = issuer;
            this.amount = amount;
            this.linearId = linearId;
            this.listOfPersistentChildTokens = listOfPersistentChildTokens;
        }

        // Default constructor required by hibernate.
        public PersistentToken() {
            this.owner = "";
            this.issuer = "";
            this.amount = 0;
            this.linearId = UUID.randomUUID();
            this.listOfPersistentChildTokens = null;
        }

        public String getOwner() {
            return owner;
        }

        public String getIssuer() {
            return issuer;
        }

        public int getAmount() {
            return amount;
        }

        public UUID getLinearId() {
            return linearId;
        }

        public List<PersistentChildToken> getChildTokens() { return listOfPersistentChildTokens; }
    }

    @Entity
    @CordaSerializable
    @Table(name = "token_child_states")
    public static class PersistentChildToken {
        @Id
        private final UUID Id;
        @Column(name = "owner")
        private final String owner;
        @Column(name = "issuer")
        private final String issuer;
        @Column(name = "amount")
        private final int amount;
        @Column(name = "child proof")
        private final String childProof;
        @ManyToOne(targetEntity = PersistentToken.class)
        private final TokenState persistentToken;

        public PersistentChildToken(String owner, String issuer, int amount) {
            this.Id = UUID.randomUUID();
            this.owner = owner;
            this.issuer = issuer;
            this.amount = amount;
            this.persistentToken = null;
            this.childProof = "I am a child";
        }

        // Default constructor required by hibernate.
        public PersistentChildToken() {
            this.Id = UUID.randomUUID();
            this.owner = "";
            this.issuer = "";
            this.amount = 0;
            this.persistentToken = null;
            this.childProof = "I am a child";
        }

        public UUID getId() {
            return Id;
        }

        public String getOwner() {
            return owner;
        }

        public String getIssuer() {
            return issuer;
        }

        public int getAmount() {
            return amount;
        }

        public TokenState getPersistentToken() {
            return persistentToken;
        }
    }
}
```

***TokenIssueFlow***

```html
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
public class TokenIssueFlow extends FlowLogic<SignedTransaction> {
    private final Party owner;
    private final int amount;

    public TokenIssueFlow(Party owner, int amount) {
        this.owner = owner;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    private final ProgressTracker progressTracker = new ProgressTracker();

    @Override
    public ProgressTracker getProgressTracker() {
        return progressTracker;
    }

    @Suspendable
    @Override
    public SignedTransaction call() throws FlowException {
        // We choose our transaction's notary (the notary prevents double-spends).
        Party notary = getServiceHub().getNetworkMapCache().getNotaryIdentities().get(0);
        // We get a reference to our own identity.
        Party issuer = getOurIdentity();

        /* ============================================================================
         *         Create our TokenState to represent on-ledger tokens
         * ===========================================================================*/

        List<TokenSchemaV1.PersistentChildToken> listOfPersistentChildTokens = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int count = 0; count <=5; count++) {
            TokenSchemaV1.PersistentChildToken child = new TokenSchemaV1.PersistentChildToken(owner.getName().toString(), issuer.getName().toString(), amount + 2);
            listOfPersistentChildTokens.add(child);
        }

        // We create our new TokenState.
        TokenState tokenState = new TokenState(issuer, owner, amount, new UniqueIdentifier(), listOfPersistentChildTokens);

        /* ============================================================================
         *      Build our token issuance transaction to update the ledger
         * ===========================================================================*/
        // We build our transaction.
        TransactionBuilder txBuilder = new TransactionBuilder();

        txBuilder.setNotary(notary);

        txBuilder.addOutputState(tokenState, TokenContract.ID);

        TokenContract.Commands.Issue commandData = new TokenContract.Commands.Issue();
        List<PublicKey> requiredSigners = ImmutableList.of(issuer.getOwningKey());
        txBuilder.addCommand(commandData, requiredSigners);

        /* ============================================================================
         *          Write our TokenContract to control token issuance!
         * ===========================================================================*/
        // We sign the transaction with our private key, making it immutable.
        SignedTransaction signedTransaction = getServiceHub().signInitialTransaction(txBuilder);

        // We check our transaction is valid based on its contracts.
        txBuilder.verify(getServiceHub());

        // We get the transaction notarised and recorded automatically by the platform.
        return subFlow(new FinalityFlow(signedTransaction));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Nick, is there a definition of `TokenSchema` anywhere?

Comment: Hey Joel! There is indeed. TokenSchema is very simple, it's just an empty class. --> public class TokenSchema {}

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you may need to add an explicit @Cascade(CascadeType.PERSIST) annotation on your @OneToMany relationship (in the parent class).

Have a look at the following working code snippet:

```
class SchemaFamily

object TestSchema : MappedSchema(SchemaFamily::class.java, 1, setOf(Parent::class.java, Child::class.java)) {
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Parents")
    class Parent : PersistentState() {
        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumns(JoinColumn(name = "transaction_id", referencedColumnName = "transaction_id"), JoinColumn(name = "output_index", referencedColumnName = "output_index"))
        @OrderColumn
        @Cascade(CascadeType.PERSIST)
        var children: MutableSet<Child> = mutableSetOf()
    }

    @Suppress("unused")
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Children")
    class Child {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name = "child_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
        var childId: Int? = null

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumns(JoinColumn(name = "transaction_id", referencedColumnName = "transaction_id"), JoinColumn(name = "output_index", referencedColumnName = "output_index"))
        var parent: Parent? = null
    }
}
```

Please adjust your code to the above and report back.

Comment: Hey Jose, that worked! I added the annotation and the child table was persisted to the DB. The java syntax for the annotation was @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)

Comment: I also had to include an @JoinColumns tag referencing the output_index, and transaction_id. If I don't include both of these fields it throws an error. Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: Hey Jose, can you share reference how to update this state.

Answer (score 0):

@Jose Coll - Thanks that was definitely it. Following up here with additional information on my implementation.

See the snippet below for a working implementation of the update schema classes. @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST) caused the child table to be persisted to the DB on initialization of the node. I also had to include an @JoinColumn tag with the appropriate fields.

```html
@CordaSerializable
public class TokenSchemaV1 extends MappedSchema {

    public TokenSchemaV1() {
        super(TokenSchema.class, 1, ImmutableList.of(PersistentToken.class, PersistentChildToken.class));
    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "token_states")
    public static class PersistentToken extends PersistentState {
        @Column(name = "owner") private final String owner;
        @Column(name = "issuer") private final String issuer;
        @Column(name = "amount") private final int amount;
        @Column(name = "linear_id") private final UUID linearId;
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
        @JoinColumns({
                @JoinColumn(name = "output_index", referencedColumnName = "output_index"),
                @JoinColumn(name = "transaction_id", referencedColumnName = "transaction_id"),
        })
        private final List<PersistentChildToken> listOfPersistentChildTokens;

        public PersistentToken(String owner, String issuer, int amount, UUID linearId, List<PersistentChildToken> listOfPersistentChildTokens) {
            this.owner = owner;
            this.issuer = issuer;
            this.amount = amount;
            this.linearId = linearId;
            this.listOfPersistentChildTokens = listOfPersistentChildTokens;
        }

        // Default constructor required by hibernate.
        public PersistentToken() {
            this.owner = "";
            this.issuer = "";
            this.amount = 0;
            this.linearId = UUID.randomUUID();
            this.listOfPersistentChildTokens = null;
        }

        public String getOwner() {
            return owner;
        }

        public String getIssuer() {
            return issuer;
        }

        public int getAmount() {
            return amount;
        }

        public UUID getLinearId() {
            return linearId;
        }

        public List<PersistentChildToken> getChildTokens() { return listOfPersistentChildTokens; }
    }

    @Entity
    @CordaSerializable
    @Table(name = "token_child_states")
    public static class PersistentChildToken {
        @Id
        private final UUID Id;
        @Column(name = "owner")
        private final String owner;
        @Column(name = "issuer")
        private final String issuer;
        @Column(name = "amount")
        private final int amount;
        @Column(name = "child_proof")
        private final String childProof;
        @ManyToOne(targetEntity = PersistentToken.class)
        private final TokenState persistentToken;

        public PersistentChildToken(String owner, String issuer, int amount) {
            this.Id = UUID.randomUUID();
            this.owner = owner;
            this.issuer = issuer;
            this.amount = amount;
            this.persistentToken = null;
            this.childProof = "I am a child";
        }

        // Default constructor required by hibernate.
        public PersistentChildToken() {
            this.Id = UUID.randomUUID();
            this.owner = "";
            this.issuer = "";
            this.amount = 0;
            this.persistentToken = null;
            this.childProof = "I am a child";
        }

        public UUID getId() {
            return Id;
        }

        public String getOwner() {
            return owner;
        }

        public String getIssuer() {
            return issuer;
        }

        public int getAmount() {
            return amount;
        }

        public TokenState getPersistentToken() {
            return persistentToken;
        }
    }
}
```