# one to many and many to many relationship in corda

Tags: corda

I have three tables, lets say T1, T2 and T3.
T1 is having one to many relationship with T2 and T2 and T3 are having many to many relationship between each other.
T1 state is updated to "completed" once multiple rows in T3 gets to a particular state and hence the dependent rows in T2 gets updated.
once all the rows of T2 gets to a completed state(dependent on T3) T1 state is updated to "completed".
I am trying to do one to many and many to many relationship between the tables but getting multiple errors.
can you suggest a correct design pattern from corda point of view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no right or wrong design here. We have tried different approaches, and different designs excel in some situations but fail miserably at others, and vice versa.

What I can advise is it depends on what your T2 or T3 is.

1. If T2/T3 correspond to documents/assets in the real world and has a parent/child relationship to T1/each other, then it's better to model them as such in the form of states and link them by `linearId` or `linearPointer`(Corda 4). And let the contract command dictate how the states should transition from one lifecycle to the other. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48277289/how-does-corda-support-parent-child-relationship)
2. If T2/T3 are objects i.e `listOfApprovers`, `listOfAttachments`, `listOfCompletedStatus`, then it's preferable to let them be a `List` object within the parent state itself. And do a `OneToMany` annotation using JPA in the schema. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53233011/corda-how-to-implement-hierarchical-relationships-between-state-data-persisted)

Comment: The first option is suiting our use case., can you please help with how to link linearId?